# Increase by 200% max length in oracle database accessed by Entity framework 6.0

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I would like to increase all max length in the fields in a oracle database, because on the application side, the viewmodel has different max length than the database and the app crashes when the user inputs more than permitted by the db.

Is there any risk of regression by just increasing the max length, there are alot of stored procedures too.

i do not want to change the application business logic.

Comment: You can restrict the users input by validating

Comment: i do not want to change the application business logic.